# Error installing Jekyll, requires Ruby >= 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I get the error

```
Error installing jekyll:
jekyll requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

when I run

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

"ruby -v" says I have ruby version 1.9.3

How do I install Jekyll?  Do I need to upgrade ruby?  If so, how?

Update - I installed ruby 2.0.0 with rvm but get the same error.  Since trying to install with gem, could that still be trying to install with the older version of ruby?  If so, how to find and change?

Comment: By updating your Ruby, the "how" depends on how you're managing your Ruby versions.

Comment: How does one manage ruby versions?

Comment: System-level install, Installer install, rvm, rbenv, ...

Comment: Installed ruby 2.0.0 but still getting the same error.  Could gem be still using the older version?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34523631/4233593) was very helpful for installing the ruby version manager, which allows you to checkout and use any version you want whenever you want in your home environment without need for `sudo`, simply run `gem install jekyll`

Comment: I have the same problem. Trying to follow all the recommendations using rbenv and bundler. The final `bundle install` fails with this "requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0." despite `rbenv version` giving 
`2.3.1 (set by /vagrant/.ruby-version)`. Here's a bash script within a vagrant file: http://pastebin.com/UTgmRQfF

Answer (score 40):

Try

```
sudo gem install jekyll -v 2.5
```

The default command apparently tries to install Jekyll 3, which was released  [on October 27th 2015](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll/versions). The 2.5 version still works with Ruby 1.9.3, and its quite allright for me, probably for you too.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34523631/4233593) was very helpful for installing the ruby version manager, which allows you to checkout and use the newest or any version you want whenever you want in your home environment without need for `sudo`, simply run `gem install jekyll`

Comment: According to some old help on Jekyll's issue page the Ubuntu package is "incredibly old" and you shouldn't use it.  https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/209

Answer (score 15):

I solved this issue the following way (assuming the `ruby2.0` package is installed):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby
sudo rm /usr/bin/gem
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby2.0 /usr/bin/ruby
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gem2.0 /usr/bin/gem
```

**Quick explanation:**

`/usr/bin/ruby` and `/usr/bin/gem` are symlinks, you can check their target by entering:

```
ll /usr/bin/ruby
ll /usr/bin/gem
```

Changing the target of these links results in changing your default ruby and gem execution. Switching to version 2.0 for instance, lets you install Jekyll 3.

Comment: This solution will break your packaging system, and might in the future make it impossible for you to upgrade. Bad solution, do not do this.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why is it breaking the packaging system? 
Also, you could always switch the symbolic links to their original target easily.

Comment: You should never mess around under /usr /usr/bin etc. - Thats what /usr/local/ is for. 

You could do ln -s /usr/bin/ruby2.0 /usr/local/bin/ruby 

That would be the correct debian-way, if you are going to mess around with symlinks.

Comment: Imho having different symlinks, from different locations, to different ruby versions is the messier of the two solutions.
And I still don't see why the packaging system would be broken.

Comment: Other solutions seems pretty easy and safe to me.

Answer (score 13):

You can give a try to:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev
sudo gem2.0 install jekyll-import
```

Comment: I had a similar stack trace like above question, it was for sass package while building in `travis-ci` 's `trusty`. Using above and doing `apt-get install build-essential` before helped.

Answer (score 4):

I try the following on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo gem2.0 install jekyll
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've already installed a later version of Ruby AND you're using rbenv, and gem gives the same error, it is because you are still using the old version of gem. There are now two executables called gem in your filesystem. Figure out which gem is the default with "which":

$ which gem

If you see something like */.rbenv/shims/gem, this is not the version of gems that you want to use. The correct version of gem will be in /.rbenv/versions/[your preferred version, i.e. 2.0.0]. You can run that version of gem by including the full path to the executable:

$ sudo /path/to/correct/gem install jekyll