# Ubuntu ruby gem location

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am trying to use the prawn gem. I am just trying out the basic hello world example, on an ubuntu machine.

```
require 'prawn'
Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
text "Hello World!"
end
```

First problem was that I was using ruby 1.9.1, it produced an error and said it needed ruby 2.0, so using RVM I updated to 2.2.1. However everytime I run this, I get this error

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot
>   load such file -- prawn (LoadError)   from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'    from
>   prawnpdf.rb:1:in `'

Now I am bit a newbie with Ubuntu and ruby for that matter, but I assume the issue is that it is looking in the wrong place for the prawn gem which I have installed ie it is looking in the old verison of ruby.

When I run `$ ruby -v`
I get

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [i686-linux]
```

what am I doing wrong? any help would be most appreicated.

Comment: did you try reinstalling prawn in your new Ruby?

Comment: I did try and reinstall prawn.  This is what I did previously  gem install prawn
Successfully installed prawn-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for prawn-2.1.0
Done installing documentation for prawn after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

Comment: also tried rvm all do gem install prawn

Comment: Try to reinstall `rvm`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34523631/3098330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the given step.

**1:** `rvm list`

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]
```

**2:** `rvm use < ruby-version >` # for instances ruby-1.9.3-p125

```
rvm use 2.2.1
```

**3:** `gem install prawn`

Would work !!!

Comment: I would have thought that it would have worked too $ rvm list rubies

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.1 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-2.2.1 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default      rvm use 2.2.1       gem install prawn
Successfully installed prawn-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for prawn-2.1.0
Done installing documentation for prawn after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
But still the same error thanks for the idea though

Comment: @D133p53: I think so, But have my answer work for you ?

Comment: @D133p53L: Once you install `prawn gem` close the `Terminal` and try with `New Terminal`.

Comment: No sorry Vinay it didn't work, I have tried new terminal.

Comment: Go to Terminal => Edit => Profile Preference => Under Title and Command menu look for option, Run Command as login shell option" "Do Checked ".

Comment: I had tried that, tried again without much luck. I have noticed that rvm has installed ruby 2.2.1 in a different location than ruby 1.9.1, /home/hamish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/ vs /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/ do you think this has any bearing on my problem?

Comment: Vinay, your solution was correct but I was too dense to see it. Just out of habit I put sudo gem install prawn, not gem install prawn. As soon as I did exactly what you were saying it worked. Thanks for your patience, your were 100% right.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you switch ruby versions with rvm, you start using a new gemset. Having previously installed `prawn` doesn't mean it is currently installed, and the error message suggests it's not installed. So:

```
rvm use 2.2.1
```

and then

```
gem install prawn
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: `rvm use 2.2.1 --default` makes more sense for this particular case.

Comment: @StephenGrimes you are right it looks if it isn't installed, I have previous used the command rvm use 2.2.1 as well as rvm use 2.2.`1 --default

Comment: Be careful if you are changing directories after the gem install or rvm command. That could effect the ruby version.

Comment: @StephenGrimes you were right on the money. I foolishly was using sudo gem install, not just gem install. Here is a paragraph from the rvm website - When you do sudo you are running commands as root, another user in another shell and hence all of the setup that RVM has done for you is ignored while the command runs under sudo. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `Gemfile` for your project so it becomes easier to maintain the dependencies.
See details: http://bundler.io/

Then cd into your project directory and install the bundle (once or after changes) and run your ruby script:

```
cd my_project
bundle install
ruby my_thing.rb
```

If you cannot/don't want to use bundler: you need to reinstall the Gem for every ruby.